# Backbonejs views not called on updating (adding) collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have default collection for my views, (header, views) apart from I am adding collection to my existing defaults.

when a new collection add to collection list, i am not getting console information about the update.

here is my code :

```
var data = [
    {name:"name1", age:"01"},
    {name:"name2", age:"02"},
    {name:"name3", age:"03"},
    {name:"name4", age:"04"},
    {name:"name5", age:"05"}
];


var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        name : "yet to be describe",
        age : "no age data"
    }
});

var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : model
});

var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function () {
        console.log ("view initiated");
    }
});

var views = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    render : function () {
         console.log ( this.collection.length ); // i am not getting updates
    }
})

var headerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function () {
         _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    render : function () {
        console.log ( this.collection.length ); // i am not getting updates
    }
})

var coll = new collection(data);
var myApp = new views({collection : coll}); // not called on update
var header = new headerView({collection : coll}); // not called on update

$("button").on("click", function () {
    coll.add({name:("name"+(coll.size()+1)), age : coll.size()+1 });
})
```

Can you one help me to figure out my issue please..?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/T3PR3/)

Comment: You need to bind events on collection. Have a look at `http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#listening-for-events`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your views i guess you want to monitor the collection an render when a model is added, so you need to bind to the collections events:

```
var views = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize : function () {
    this.collection.bind('add', this.render, this); //Binding render to the collections add event
  },
  render : function () {
     console.log ( this.collection.length );
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind events on your collection :

```
var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : model,
    initialize : function(){
        this.on('add', function(){
           /// DO what needs to be done on adding model to collection
            myApp.render(); 
           header.render();
        })
    }
});
```